# Printing a character a variable number of times with println

Tags: rust

I want to use `println!` and the powerful formatting tools of `format!` to print a character a specific number of times. Of course this is possible with a loop, like so:

```
fn give_love(count: usize) {
    print!("Here is love for you: ");
    for i in 0..count {
        print!("♥");
    }
    println!("");
}
```

But I neither want to write the loop nor the three `print`s. How to do this shorter/better?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Solution to your code

```
fn give_love(count: usize) {
    println!("Here is love for you: {:♥<1$}", "", count);
}
```

---

### Explanation

You can (mis-)use the fill feature that allows to fill a printed value with some character of your choice. The grammar for this feature alone looks like:

```
'{' ':' <fill> <align> <width> '}'
```

Where `width` is either a constant number or a reference to an argument of type `<argument_index> '$'`. So `3` would mean a width of constant 3 and `1$` would mean a width of the value of the 1st argument of `println!`.

---

However: here we are kind of "misusing" this feature and we mustn't forget that we are only specifying the "fill" for some other printable thing, which is passed by argument to `println`. This can be an empty string though.

```
println!("love: {:♥<3}", "");     // love: ♥♥♥
println!("love: {:♥<1$}", "", 5); // love: ♥♥♥♥♥
```

Here are some examples where we don't pass an empty string:

```
println!("love: {:♥<5}", "#");    // love: #♥♥♥♥
println!("love: {:♥>5}", "#");    // love: ♥♥♥♥#
println!("love: {:♥^5}", "#");    // love: ♥♥#♥♥
```

Comment: or (to mention a less clever alternative), you could `repeat('♥').take(count).collect::<String>()`

Answer (score 6):

If you want a cleaner way to repeat any `Display`able item without creating an intermediate allocation, you can create a wrapper struct and write a custom `Display` implementation that performs the repetition:

```
use std::fmt::{self, Display};

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct DisplayRepeat<T>(usize, T);

impl<T: Display> Display for DisplayRepeat<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        for _ in 0..self.0 {
            self.1.fmt(f)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn repeat<T>(times: usize, item: T) -> DisplayRepeat<T> {
    DisplayRepeat(times, item)
}

fn main() {
    println!("Here is love for you: {}", repeat(10, '♥'));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since 1.16 you can use `.repeat()` like so:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Here is love for you: {}", "♥".repeat(10));
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7b9e55c0cc41c25a01179408f7097330)

Comment: Note that unlike the other two answers, this allocates a `String`. Granted: this small overhead likely does not matter in the majority of use cases for this, so it's a perfectly fine solution.