# How do I print a character N number of times in Rust?

Tags: printing, rust, char

I would like to print a specific character N number of times via one call (i.e. no looping) to the `print!` macro in Rust. How might I go about doing this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280798/printing-a-character-a-variable-number-of-times-with-println) answer your question?

Comment: [here's a solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69fbe5148357fafec0a392499fdfe0cd) if you need a variable character repeated