# Rust std::fmt formating parameters. Is [fill] from variable possible?

Tags: rust, format

Is it possible to use a fill character from a variable?

```rust
println!("love: {:♥<5}", "#");    // love: #♥♥♥♥
println!("love: {:♥>5}", "#");    // love: ♥♥♥♥#
println!("love: {:♥^5}", "#");    // love: ♥♥#♥♥
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35280799/18392410

I would like to to draw what is the `♥` in that example from a variable.

"It shouldn't be to alien"... based on the docs, but at least at my current level it's quite hard to get a solid understanding.

```
format_string := <text> [ maybe-format <text> ] *
maybe-format := '{' '{' | '}' '}' | <format>
format := '{' [ argument ] [ ':' format_spec ] '}'
argument := integer | identifier

format_spec := [[fill]align][sign]['#']['0'][width]['.' precision][type]
fill := character
align := '<' | '^' | '>'
sign := '+' | '-'
width := count
precision := count | '*'
type := identifier | ''
count := parameter | integer
parameter := argument '$'
```

reference to formatting syntax: https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/std/fmt/index.html#syntaxL

Trying and searching through the docs led to no result. There doesn't seem to be an example on it. Currently, I'm using `.repeat()` to work around the desired solution.

Comment: Use the proper [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/index.html), those docs are from rust 1.25. We're currently in about 1.65 / 1.66